# How to Download Android System Image (For Emulator) Externally?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i download Android N system image for emulator externally?

If i download from Android Studio there are many problems

**1.** I have to wait until the download completes.

**2.** If the download interrupts, i have to start the download again from 0%.

**So what's the procedure for downloading the system image externally and then placing it in proper location (i.e android folder) ?**

Any tutorial?

Comment: I do not believe that there is any documented support for this at the present time. If you look at the transcript of the Android SDK download stuff in Android Studio, you should see the URL that is being used to download that particular image (or other piece of the SDK).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you can use the external sdk manager. you can launch it manually or you can click SDK Manager icon in android studio toolbar and then Launch Standalone SDK Manager at the bottom of new opened window.

Using external sdk manager should be the preferred option also to update

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a similar question here:

[How to install android system image (for Emulator) externally in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397208/how-to-install-android-system-image-for-emulator-externally-in-android-studio)

Duplicate??