# How to install android system image (for Emulator) externally in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have downloaded (externally from IDM) Android N System Image from [this](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sysimg_x86_64-24_r06.zip) link. Now where should i paste, install the file or what should i do with the file?

I want Android N to show in my Android Emulator list (list which appears after clicking the run button in Android Studio).

Comment: Need to have latest sdk version to use Android N if u don't have an updated version update first..and also check for intel Haxm ...

Answer (score 1):

Unpack this zip into folder `{sdk_dir}/system-images/android-24/default/`

After it you must create new virtual device from run dialog usiing this system image.

[image: Select this system image]

Comment: I did the same but nothing shows in the Android Emulator LIst

Comment: @ak47 This won't work there some additional set up that android studio does

Answer (score 0):

Unpack to `{SDK_PATH}/system-images/android-24/google_apis/x86/`
Refresh the emulators list by clicking the reload button at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

*follow this hierarchy
*C:\android-sdk\system-images\android-R\google_apis_playstore
inside the last directory which is the google_apis_playstore unpack the zip file which is system image downloaded

open AndS(android studio), click create virtual device, browse to x86 images

your device should be in the list

Answer (score -1):

You should put the downloaded system images in {Sdk_location}/temp and then use command line to install them otherwise they won't show up in android studio.

Comment: A worthless reply, since it does not explain at all _how_ to do that.